# Python: Order of graph objects, bring line in front of everything

Tags: python, graph, line

I have a graph with multiple objects, I need to keep in front of everything the lines (or better I need to define the order of objects).

I tried with zorder command, but I did get the expected results.

```
fig10, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(24,12))
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = '12'
plt.rcParams["axes.edgecolor"] = "black"
plt.rcParams["axes.linewidth"] = 2
ax.set_title('MW66: Soggiacenza falda vs Spessore Prodotto', fontsize=18,fontweight="bold")
ax.plot(periodo, assey1, '-o', color="navy", linewidth = 3,label = 'Soggiacenza Falda [m da b.p.]',zorder=1)
ax.set_facecolor("#ffffff")
ax.set_xlabel('', fontsize=18)
ax.set_ylabel('Soggiacenza Falda [m da b.p.]', color="black", fontsize=15)
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
ax.grid()
#ax.set_xlim(periodo.min() - timedelta(days=2), periodo.max() + timedelta(days=2))
ax.set_xlim([date(2022, 9, 23),  today+ timedelta(days=2)]) #datetime.date(2021, 1, 8)]
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=7)) #ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d"))
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
ax.axvline(dt.datetime(2023, 1, 30),linewidth=2, color='black')
ax.axvline(dt.datetime(2023, 3, 27),linewidth=2, color='fuchsia')
#ax.axvline(dt.datetime(2023, 1, 30),linewidth=2, color='lime')
ax.text(dt.datetime(2023, 1, 27), 6.55, 'Pompa Pneumatica', rotation='vertical',color='black',fontweight="bold",fontsize=18)
ax.text(dt.datetime(2023, 3, 24), 6.55 , 'Elettropompa Sommersa - P&T', rotation='vertical',color='fuchsia',fontweight="bold",fontsize=18)
#ax.text(dt.datetime(2022, 11, 19), 6.9, 'Sommersa', rotation='vertical',color='fuchsia',fontweight="bold",fontsize=18)
#ax.text(dt.datetime(2023, 1, 27), 5.75, 'Avvio P&T', rotation='vertical',color='lime',fontweight="bold",fontsize=18)
ax.set_ylim(7,4)
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

## Asse Secondario
ax2=ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(periodo2, assey2_spess, color="orange",linewidth = 3,label = 'Spessore Prodotto [m]',zorder=1)
#ax2.bar(periodo2, assey2_spess,width = 0.8, color = 'Orange', alpha=0.8,label = 'Spessore Prodotto [m]')
#ax2.axhline(CSC, color = 'red', linestyle = '--',linewidth = 3, label = 'CSC', alpha= 0.75)
ax2.set_ylabel('Spessore Prodotto [m]',color="black",fontsize=18,rotation=90)
ax2.set_ylim(0,0.5)
plt.fill_between(periodo2, 0, assey2_spess, lw=0, color='orange', alpha= 0.75,zorder=3)
 
lines, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
lines2, labels2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax2.legend(lines + lines2, labels + labels2, bbox_to_anchor=(0.45, -0.08),ncol=3, frameon=False, loc='upper center',fontsize=15)

fig10.tight_layout()
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sure, on this link https://ibb.co/Mf9rxGY you can find the example, I need to put those lines in front of everything else